# Create Function to get Next Number (including decimals)

Tags: javascript

I've created a function that returns the next number taking into account decimals, but am having an issue when the input number has a zero (0) proceeding the decimal.

```
const getNextValue = (input) => {
    const newNumber = input
        .toString()
        .replace(/\d+$/, (number) =>
            parseInt(number) +1)

    return parseFloat(newNumber)
}

console.log(getNextValue(3.3)) // returns 3.4 as it should
console.log(getNextValue(3.34)) // returns 3.35 as it should
console.log(getNextValue(3.002)) // returns 3.3 as it ignores the zeros
```

Comment: Check your example. All your console logs are the same

Comment: `toString` and than `parseInt` but you're interested in decimals?... Why that complicated? next highest number? Next to what?

Comment: How can `3.3` return both `3.4` and `3.35`?

Comment: He has an error in his question but means `3.30` and wants to do an operation on the trailing zero, which then doesn't exist anymore. Oof i've seen too many of these that i think i already know where this is going.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Except that would presumably be expected to return `3.31`, not `3.35`.

Comment: Copy pasted console logs, and forgot to change the values. Fixed examples

Comment: Have you tried your code with `3.9`? Do you expect the result `3.1`?

Comment: To better understand the goal of your function, which result do you expect with 3.002 input ?

Comment: @Philippe I would expect 3.003

Comment: @jabaa No that is not the expected result. I would expect 4

Comment: You only consider the digits after `.` and don't modify the digits before `.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could skip the zeros:

```js
const getNextValue = (input) => {
    const newNumber = input
        .toString()
        .replace(/^\d+$|[1-9]+$/, (number) =>
            parseInt(number) + 1);

    return parseFloat(newNumber)
}

console.log(getNextValue(3.3)) // returns 3.4 as it should
console.log(getNextValue(3.34)) // returns 3.35 as it should
console.log(getNextValue(3.002)) // returns 3.003
console.log(getNextValue(30)) // returns 31
```

A completely different approach that should solve all the mentioned issues. I've added the character `'1'` in front of the decimal places to avoid the problem with leading zeros and to store the carry. At the end I add the carry and remove this character.

```js
const getNextValue = (input) => {
    const str = input.toString();
    if (!str.includes('.')) return input + 1;
    const numbers = str.split('.');
    const dec = (+('1' + numbers[1]) + 1).toString();
    return parseFloat(`${+numbers[0] + +dec[0] - 1}.${dec.substring(1)}`);
}

console.log(getNextValue(3.3)) // returns 3.4 as it should
console.log(getNextValue(3.34)) // returns 3.35 as it should
console.log(getNextValue(3.002)) // returns 3.003
console.log(getNextValue(3.9)) // returns 4
console.log(getNextValue(3.09)) // returns 3.1
console.log(getNextValue(30)) // returns 31
```

Comment: doesn't work for multiples of 10
console.log(getNextValue(30)) // returns 30 should be 31

Comment: Not correct, The code in the question change 30 to 31, You can try it yourself.

Comment: @M3Ali That's not intuitive for me. I expected the result `40`. But I fixed it.

Comment: I wonder about 3.9, which becomes 3.1, simply because 9+1=10 and then it parses "3.10“... OP does not mention numbers ending in a 9, so not really your fault, but still.

Comment: I know, but the whole idea of adding 1 to a subseries of digits is not very suited as a solution to this problem unless rollover is also considered.

Comment: @PeterB Fixed it